# Regex replace removing <br> from html

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have text like this:

```
test<br>
test<br>
test<br>
test<br>
```

I'm trying to create a simple search program but when my script finds a match all the text appears on one line with the matched term highlighted. I want the term to be highlighted but to keep the text on separate lines.

Here the search button event code calls this function:

```
function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm) {
    if (searchTerm) {
        var searchTermRegEx, matches;
        var selector = "#realTimeContents";
        $(selector + ' span.match').each(function () {
            $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
        });
        try {
            searchTermRegEx = new RegExp('(' + searchTerm + ')', "ig");
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
        matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
        if (matches !== null && matches.length > 0) {
            var txt = $(selector).text().replace(searchTermRegEx, '<span class="match">$1</span>');
            $(selector).html(txt);
            searchIndex++;
            $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');
            //if($('.match').eq(searchIndex).offset().top > $('#realTimeContents').height()-10){
            $('#realTimeContents').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.match').eq(searchIndex).get(0).offsetTop
            });

            return true;
        } else {
            alert('Search not found.');
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here's a fiddle showing the problem:  http://jsfiddle.net/HQq9Y/2/

Comment: Please include relevant code in your question on StackOverflow, and not solely on an other website (such as jsfiddle). You forgot to include the library in your fiddle, but even when I include the library, I cannot figure out what you mean. Please make your question clearer.

Comment: sorry by mistake ..use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/HQq9Y/2/

Comment: actually when I am implementing the search functionality found code from stackoverflow but when i search text it accumulated in single line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `searchAndHighlight` function, you're doing this :

```
 var txt = $(selector).text().replace(searchTermRegEx, '<span class="match">$1</span>');
```

Change `text()` to `html()`. Since its `text` and not `html`, its not recognizing the `br` tag.

```
var txt = $(selector).html().replace(searchTermRegEx, '<span class="match">$1</span>');
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/HQq9Y/3/